# Parsing a XML child element back as a string

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse a complex XML and xpath isn't behaving like I thought it would.
Here's my sample xml:

```
<project>
    <samples>
        <sample>show my balance</sample>
        <sample>show me the <subsample value='USD'>money</subsample>today</sample>
    </samples>
</project>
```

Here's my python code:

```
from lxml import etree

somenode="<project><samples><sample>show my balance</sample><sample>show me the <subsample value='USD'>money</subsample>today</sample></samples></project>"

somenode_etree = etree.fromstring(somenode)

for x in somenode_etree.iterfind(".//sample"):
    print (etree.tostring(x))
```

I get the output:

```
b'<sample>show my balance</sample><sample>show me the <subsample value="USD">money</subsample>today</sample></samples></project>'
b'<sample>show me the <subsample value="USD">money</subsample>today</sample></samples></project>'
```

when I expected:

```
show my balance
show me the <subsample value="USD">money</subsample>today
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you want back? Text or XML? Difficult and a bit strange to want both. And strange may indicate an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe your overall problem and goal.

Comment: I want the anything between the <sample></sample> tags back as a string to process it into a different data format. 

LMC confirmed that the erroneous output was due to a bug and my code will get me the expected output otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will get text and elements as expected

```
result = somenode_etree.xpath(".//sample/text() | .//sample/*")
result
['show my balance', 'show me the ', <Element subsample at 0x7f0516cfa288>, 'today']
```

Printing found nodes as OP requested

```
for x in somenode_etree.xpath(".//sample/text() | .//sample/*[node()]"):
    if type(x) == etree._Element:
        print(etree.tostring(x, method='xml',with_tail=False).decode('UTF-8'))
    else:
        print(x)
```

Result

```
show my balance
show me the 
<subsample value="USD">money</subsample>
today
```

`with_tail` argument [prevents tail text to be appended to element](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1970044).

Or

```
>>> for x in somenode_etree.xpath(".//sample/text() | .//sample/*"):
...     if type(x) == etree._Element:
...         print(x.text)
...     else:
...         print(x)
... 
show my balance
show me the 
money
today
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the output exactly as in the expected output with a oneliner? Including the subsample tags etc

Comment: Sure. A good exercise for you ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the code I pasted in the question doesn't give the expected answer. I've tried the same xpath expression in an online tester (https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)  and get the expected output.
I've also tried it on a laptop with an older version of python/lxml from 2021 and it works there too. Yet this code doesn't work on a new install of Anaconda. I'm trying to understand what changed and how to work around it.

Comment: You are getting the `sample` elements, not their descendants.

Comment: @C.L. Updated the answer to print result as you expected. Looks like there's a bug on lxml.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for confirming it's a bug.

Comment: @C.L. not a bug lol. Updated my answer with proper `tostring()` option. It's weird anyway, none implementation I know of `tails` text to the element when printing (java, xmllint).

Comment: yes, I saw that on the bug report. I get that you provided an alternative solution but do you know why I can't just use the XPATH ".//sample" to get what I need. It used to work and now it doesn't and I cannot figure out which version implemented the change that broke this. Any online XPATH tester shows my expected answer but lxml seems to do it differently.